# How can my Flutter application disable or enable an existing alarm?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How can I programmatically in Flutter disable and then re-enable one of the existing alarms ?

[image]

Comment: Is this screenshot from your own app or the Android clock app?

Comment: This is the Android clock app on an Androis emulator.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't do that. You can't just reach into another app and modify it's state, for security reasons. The app would have to have some kind of API for 3rd party apps to interact with it, which few apps do. The best you can do is maybe [launch the clock app via an Intent](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents)

Comment: You could of course create your own alarms in your own app using something like the [android_alarm_manager_plus package](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus)